# Selection if option value greater than something, display alert

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple select tag each option has a numeric value
I'm trying to limit the selected choices when their values exceeds a defined value
right now it's only working for single choices and not when selecting multiple choices
here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var last_selection = null;
      var num = 4;
      $('select#multi_limit').change(function(event) {
          if ($(this).val() > num) {
            $(this).val(last_selection);
            alert('You can select options which their values dont exceeds 4 ');
            }
            else {
              last_selection = $(this).val();
            }
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multi_limit" required name="activity[]" class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="2">Printers</option>
  <option value="3">Screens</option>
  <option value="5">Keyboards</option>
  <option value="6">Mouses</option>
  <option value="7">Computers</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the length and not the `val()` so `val().length` shall be what you gotta use. And you need to set the limit to 3 and not 4 here.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
         

              var last_selection = null;
         var num = 6;

              $('select#multi_limit').change(function(event) {
                let sum = $(this).val().reduce((a,b) => +a + +b , 0);
                console.log('sum',sum);
                if ( sum > num) {

                  $(this).val(last_selection);
                  alert('You can select upto 3 options only');
                } else {
                  last_selection = $(this).val();


                }
              });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multi_limit" required name="activity[]" class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="2">Printers</option>
        <option value="3">Screens</option>
        <option value="5">Keyboards</option>
        <option value="6">Mouses</option>
        <option value="7">Computers</option>
    </select>
```

Update as you referred in comment you need the sum instead you can add to get the sum first. `.reduce((a,b) => a+b , 0)`

Comment: sorry the alert was incorrect i've edited it, looking to sum the options values and then display the edited alert when the sum of the options values exceeds 4

Comment: weird works for single selection but when selecting two or more it always display the alert even when their sum values doesn't exceed 4

Comment: I think you're weak at math as well your minimum value is 2 if you add 2 to any other value you'll get a sum greater then 4.

Comment: LOL, obviously no... actually changed the value of "num" to something like 1000 and only then your code allowed me to select more than two options, i think it's giving huge numbers and not actually doing sums

Comment: My bad the type conversion was failing my case I've fixed please accept the answer if this is what you wanted

Comment: My pleasure buddy

Answer (score 0):

You can check selected length like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var last_selection = null;
  var num = 4;
  $('#multi_limit').change(function(event) {
    if ($("#multi_limit :selected").length > num) {
      alert('You can select options which their values dont exceeds 4');
    } else {
      last_selection = $(this).val();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multi_limit" required name="activity[]" class="multiselect form-control" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="2">Printers</option>
  <option value="3">Screens</option>
  <option value="5">Keyboards</option>
  <option value="6">Mouses</option>
  <option value="7">Computers</option>
</select>
```

Comment: -Edited- sorry the alert was not related , looking to sum the options values and display the edited alert when they exceeds value 4